# How to store variable when looping a function - javascript closure

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code to work with:

```
function loopingFunction(){

    if(typeof(foo)=="undefined"){
        var foo = 0;
    }

    alert(foo);

    if(foo==0){
        // some codes here
    }

    foo++;
}
```

The loopingFunction gets called multiple times, and each time my variable foo remains the same..somehow it is lost when i try to increment it

The counter does not seem to work which would increment the var foo each time the function is called..

Is there any workaround for this?
Any help would much be appreciated..

FYI i cannot make foo global, i have to find a workaround using closure..

Comment: where are you call the loopingFunction() in your code. we didn't see

Comment: It is being called from outside..

Comment: Show the full code man

Comment: I think you should move foo outside of your function.

Comment: foo variable local make it as global

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare `foo` inside the function. It is scoped to that function. Every time the function is called, you create a new variable called `foo`.

Declare it outside if you want to reuse the same variable.

```js
var foo;

function loopingFunction() {

  if (typeof foo === "undefined") {
    foo = 0;
  }

  alert(foo);

  if (foo == 0) {
    // some codes here
  }

  foo++;
}

loopingFunction();
loopingFunction();
loopingFunction();
```

You could perform all your initialisation outside the loop too to simply things.

```js
var foo = 0;

function loopingFunction() {

  alert(foo);

  if (foo == 0) {
    // some codes here
    // … these could probably be moved outside the function too
  }

  foo++;
}

loopingFunction();
loopingFunction();
loopingFunction();
```

If you want to keep `foo` from being global you can use a closure:

```js
var loopingFunction = function() {

  var foo = 0;

  function loopingFunction() {

    alert(foo);

    if (foo == 0) {
      // some codes here
      // … these could probably be moved outside the function too
    }

    foo++;
  }

  return loopingFunction;

}();

loopingFunction();
loopingFunction();
loopingFunction();
```

Comment: Is there anyway i can avoid declaring a global variable.. can a closure be applied here?

Comment: @wasiim_dev -  Yes, you can use a closure.

Answer (score 0):

You are declarating local variable. You must to initialize as global by two ways:

## way 1

```
var foo = 0;
function looping....
```

## way 2

```
 if(typeof(foo)=="undefined"){
    foo = 0; // without var is global 
 }
```

Comment: The second option won't work in strict mode. Implicit globals are not recommended.

Comment: Sorry, but if you type `window.foo = 0` it will be ok?

Comment: Because of this I put it in the second way, the first way is that I use. I like to define namespace to do that: `window.Namespace.foo = 0`

Answer (score 0):

You declared **foo** variable is local make it as global variable.

```
var foo;

function loopingFunction(){
    if(typeof(foo)=="undefined"){
        foo = 0;
    }
    if(!foo){
        // some codes here
    }
    foo++;
}
```